# WPF - Bind to Dictionary Key Only

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dictionary, listbox

I have a Listbox that is binded to a Dictionary.
The dictionary contains a keyword and a string.

```
 <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding PatientImgResources, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey}"  DisplayMemberPath="Key" />
```

PatientImgResources is the Dictionary
SelectedKey is the Value I want,
DisplayMemberPath just shows the keyword.

I want this keyword as my value, unfortunately SelectedKey always contains the whole dictionary entry, keyword plus value.
I tried SelectedValuePath="Key" . didn't work so far.

Is it possible to bind to the key? I don't want to use stripped dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ItemSource Binding use "PatientImgResources.Keys" instead of "PatientImgResources"...

Comment: try using "Keys" in the place of "Key"... PatientImgResources.Keys